# SQL Server Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that contains the following dates (`OpenDate`, `ClosedDate`, `WinnerAnnouncedDate`).

I have 3 rows, for 3 different categories.

I'm trying to figure out how I would get the following scenario:

Today is 14th March. I want to find out which category had the winner announced, but the following category hasn't started yet.

So if `Row 1` had `OpenDate = 12th Feb`, `ClosedDate = 10th March`, `WinnerAnnounced = 12th March`
Row 2 had an `OpenDate` of `16th March` I need it to find Row 1 because the winner has been announced, but the following category hasn't opened yet.

This may seem a little confusing, so I'll be ready to clear things up if required.

Comment: Better provide some sample data and expected resutl.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're saying, but I think it's something like:
Find the last winner announced from categories that have a start date earlier than now.

If that's the case then something like this might work for you. I'm assuming that your table is called #dates as you haven't included the table name

```
create table #dates (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    openDate datetime,
    closedDate datetime,
    WinnerAnnouncedDate datetime
)

insert into #dates
values ('12 feb 2012', '10 march 2012', '13 march 2012')


insert into #dates
values ('12 feb 2012', '10 march 2012', null)

insert into #dates
values ('16 mar 2012', null, null)


select * 
from #dates
where id = (select max(id) from #dates where openDate <= getdate() and winnerAnnouncedDate is not null)


--drop table #dates
```

Comment: Please learn to use unambiguous date string literals. The dates you've specified won't work for e.g. not english language users in SQL Server. Whereas `'20120212'` will always specify the 12th of Feburary 2012.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. For production code I would use 20120212, however for the purposes of this example I find the '12 feb 2012' easier to read

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM atable
WHERE WinnerAnnouncedDate <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY WinnerAnnouncedDate
```

[`WITH TIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) will return several rows if several `WinnerAnnouncedDate` values match the condition and have the same top value.